Manejo de variables entre kivy y python
estoy intentando extraer las variables introducidas, hacer cálculos algo complejos en python y mostrar resultados entre los distintos widgets. Sin embargo, no tengo muy claro la forma de acceder a ellas y mostrarlas en kivy, si bien sí que consigo trabajarlas en el código python.
Por ejemplo, he intentado mostrar en un label de SubWidget2 la variable tir_nom que almaceno al salir de SubWiget1. He intentado root, parent, ids,... y sus combinaciones, todas las soluciones que he visto en la web.
Seguro que alguien me dice en qué fijame. Gracias de antemano.
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, StringProperty, BooleanProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox

Builder.load_string('''

<SubWidget1>:
    id: pantallaorigen
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        text: 'Datos del TIRADOR'
    TextInput:
        id: tir_nom_inp
        hint_text: 'Tirador: '
        multiline: False
    TextInput:
        id: tir_x_inp
        hint_text: 'X: '
        multiline: False
    TextInput:
        id: tir_y_inp
        hint_text: 'Y: '
        multiline: False
    TextInput:
        id: tir_z_inp
        hint_text: 'Z: '
        multiline: False
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: 'arma1'
        CheckBox:
            id: check_arma1
            group: 'arma'
        Label:
            text: 'arma2'
        CheckBox:
            id: check_arma2
            group: 'arma'
        Label:
            text: 'arma3'
        CheckBox:
            id: check_arma3
            group: 'arma'
    Button:
        text: 'Pasar a objetivo'
        on_press: root.parent.number += 1
        size_hint: 1, 1
        on_press: root.parent.guardar_tir()
    Button:
        text: 'SALIR'
        on_press: app.stop()
        size_hint: 1, 1

<SubWidget2>:
    id: pantallaobj
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        text: 'Datos del OBJETIVO'
    TextInput:
        id: obj_nom_inp
        hint_text: 'Numeración: '
        multiline: False
    TextInput:
        id: obj_x_inp
        hint_text: 'X: '
        multiline: False
    TextInput:
        id: obj_y_inp
        hint_text: 'Y: '
        multiline: False
    TextInput:
        id: obj_z_inp
        hint_text: 'Z: '
        multiline: False
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: 'Corregir'
        CheckBox:
            id: check_corregir
    Button:
        text: 'Continuar'
        on_press: root.parent.number -= 1
        on_press: root.parent.guardar_obj()
        size_hint: 1, 1
    Button:
        text: 'SALIR'
        on_press: app.stop()
        size_hint: 1, 1
        
<SubWidget3>:
    id: pantallaobs
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        text: 'Datos OBS'
    TextInput:
        id: obs_nom_inp
        hint_text: 'Indicativo: '
        multiline: False
    TextInput:
        id: obs_x_inp
        hint_text: 'X: '
        multiline: False
    TextInput:
        id: obs_y_inp
        hint_text: 'Y: '
        multiline: False
    TextInput:
        id: obs_z_inp
        hint_text: 'Z: '
        multiline: False
    TextInput:
        id: oav_olo_inp
        hint_text: 'OLO: '
        multiline: False
    Button:
        text: 'Continuar'
        on_press: root.parent.number -= 1
        on_press: root.parent.guardar_obs()
        size_hint: 1, 1
    Button:
        text: 'SALIR'
        on_press: app.stop()
        size_hint: 1, 1

<MyWidget>:
    id: raiz
    number: 0
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        text: 'CALCULADOR'
        size_hint: 1, .1
''')

class SubWidget1(BoxLayout):
    pass

class SubWidget2(BoxLayout):
    pass
    
class SubWidget3(BoxLayout):
    pass

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    number = NumericProperty()
    tir_nom = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(*args)
        self.widget = None
        self._create_widget()

    def _create_widget(self):
        print(self.number)
        if self.widget is not None:
            self.remove_widget(self.widget)
        if self.number == 1:
            self.widget = SubWidget2()
        elif self.number == 2:
            self.widget = SubWidget3()
        else:
            self.widget = SubWidget1()
        self.add_widget(self.widget)
        
    def guardar_tir(self):
        self.tir_nom = self.children[0].ids.tir_nom_inp.text
        self.tir_x = int(self.children[0].ids.tir_x_inp.text)
        self.tir_y = int(self.children[0].ids.tir_y_inp.text)
        self.tir_z = int(self.children[0].ids.tir_z_inp.text)
        self.arma1 = self.children[0].ids.check_arma1.state
        self.arma2 = self.children[0].ids.check_arma2.state
        self.arma3 = self.children[0].ids.check_arma3.state
        print(self.tir_nom)
        
    def guardar_obj(self):
        self.obj_nom = self.children[0].ids.obj_nom_inp.text
        self.obj_x = int(self.children[0].ids.obj_x_inp.text)
        self.obj_y = int(self.children[0].ids.obj_y_inp.text)
        self.obj_z = int(self.children[0].ids.obj_z_inp.text)
        self.corregir = self.children[0].ids.check_corregir.state
        print(self.tir_nom)
        
    def guardar_obs(self):
        self.obs_nom = self.children[0].ids.obs_nom_inp.text
        self.obs_x = int(self.children[0].ids.obs_x_inp.text)
        self.obs_y = int(self.children[0].ids.obs_y_inp.text)
        self.obs_z = int(self.children[0].ids.obs_z_inp.text)
        self.olo = int(self.children[0].ids.obs_olo_inp.text)
        print(self.tir_nom)

    def on_number(self, obj, value):
        self._create_widget()

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()


Me imagino que tu desconcierto se debe a que en la misma clase:
<SubWidget2>:
    Label:
        text: root.parent.tir_nom          # <<< Esto genera un error

    # ...

    Button:
        text: 'Continuar'
        on_press: root.parent.number -= 1  # <<< Esto funciona perfectamente

En realidad no es un problema de como hacer referencia a la variable, puedes hacer referencia a ella mediante root.parent, el problema no es ese, es un problema de tiempos.
¿Dónde se origina el error?
Mejor veamos un ejemplo ultra simplificado pero reproducible:
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder



Builder.load_string('''
<SubWidget>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        text: root.parent.tir_nom
''')

class SubWidget(BoxLayout):
    pass


class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    tir_nom = StringProperty("Hola mundo")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.widget = None
        self._create_widget()

    def _create_widget(self):
        self.widget = SubWidget()
        self.add_widget(self.widget)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
    

Si lo ejecutas verás que se produce la siguiente excepción:
 >>    5:        text: root.parent.tir_nom
 ...
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tir_nom'

El problema es que se accede a root.parent cuando se instancia SubWidget con la finalidad de obtener el texto a mostrar en su Label hijo, es decir, el intento de acceder a la property tiene lugar al ejecutar la linea:
self.widget = SubWidget()

pero en este momento el widget no tiene ningún padre, el atributo parent existe pero es None, de ahí el error.
El padre se asigna cuando el widget se agrega al árbol de la app mediante el método add_widget, es decir, el widget no tendrá un padre hasta que se complete la ejecucion de:
 self.add_widget(self.widget)

¿Entonces, por qué en el botón si funciona root.parent.number?
En este caso no hay problema porque se accede a la variable después de que el usario haga click en el botón, en ese momento el widget obviamente está visible en pantalla y ya se ha llamado self.add_widget(self.widget), por lo que root.parent es una referencia válida a la instancia de Widget y no None.
¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?
Sin necesidad de cambiar la estructura de la App, tienes varias posibilidades. Por ejemplo, puedes pasarle una referencia de la property o del padre al inicializador:
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder



Builder.load_string('''
<SubWidget>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        id: label
        text: ""
''')

class SubWidget(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):    #  <<<<
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.ids.label.text = parent.tir_nom        #  <<<<


class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    tir_nom = StringProperty("Hola mundo")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.widget = None
        self._create_widget()

    def _create_widget(self):
        self.widget = SubWidget(self)               # <<<<
        self.add_widget(self.widget)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()

Otra opción, que personalmente me gusta más porque es más flexible, es usar el evento generado por la property parent:
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder



Builder.load_string('''
<SubWidget>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        id: label
        text: ""
''')

class SubWidget(BoxLayout):
    def on_parent(self, _, parent):               # <<<<
        self.ids.label.text = parent.tir_nom      # <<<<

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    tir_nom = StringProperty("Hola mundo")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.widget = None
        self._create_widget()

    def _create_widget(self):
        self.widget = SubWidget()
        self.add_widget(self.widget)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()

Si la property cambiara en el padre mientras el widget hijo existe y quisieras que el cambio se reflejara en el también, simplemente enlazalas:
def on_parent(self, _, parent):
    self.ids.label.text = parent.tir_nom
    parent.bind(tir_nom=self.ids.label.setter("text"))

Edición
Si se usa on_parent y se elimina el widget mediante los métodos remove_widget()/clear_widgets() del padre, la callback también será llamada ya que la property parent será reasignada y volverá a ser None. Esto causa una excepción en on_parent al intentar acceder al atributo como comenta el OP:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tir_nom'

Se puede solucinar simplemente con un condicional:
class SubWidget(BoxLayout):
    def on_parent(self, _, parent):
        if parent is not None:
            self.ids.label.text = parent.tir_nom

o incluso de  forma más genérica:
class SubWidget(BoxLayout):
    def on_parent(self, _, parent):
        if hasattr(parent, "tir_nom"):
            self.ids.label.text = parent.tir_nom

De forma que si el padre no tiene el atributo tir_nom no se haga nada. También podemos directamente manejar la excepción:
class SubWidget(BoxLayout):
    def on_parent(self, _, parent):
        try:
            self.ids.label.text = parent.tir_nom
        except AttributeError:
            pass


Gracias! Entonces ¿el segundo método modifica el widget en cualquier momento en que se actúe sobre el parent? Impresionante! Por otro lado, ¿me recomiendas que continúe haciendo los cálculos en MyWidget para mostrar los resultados e inputs desde SubWidgets? No me importa reestructurar el código si me resulta didáctico.

Por cierto, en el primer párrafo me has leído la mente.

Jeje, si cuando usas parent.bind(tir_nom=self.ids.label.setter("text")) si modificas tir_nom se modificar automáticamente también la etiqueta del otro widget. Si además lo usas en on_parent si cambias eventualemente el padre del widget el texto de la etiqueta también se adaptara automaticamente al contenido de la variable tir_nom de su nuevo padre.

Funcionó de maravilla, pero ahora me aparece un error al tratar de eliminar ese widget y pasar al SubWidget5, como si evaluase de nuevo on_parent y ya no encuentra las variables:
self.ids.mostrar_tir.text = 'Tirador: ' + parent.tir_nom
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tir_nom'

@Juanma_jp pues tienes razón, se me pasó esa situación. Supongo que usas  remove_widget sin más  y es que en tal caso, efectivamente se evalua de nuevo on_parent porque le estamos volviendo a asignar  None  como padre. Tiene una solución simple, he editado la respueta mira al final de ella.
